# How to only allow a group for network access?

Tags: group, openbsd, pf

Using OpenBSD's pf.

**Question:** How can we modify the firewall of OpenBSD to allow ONLY a given group for network access? If somebody isn't in that group, it shouldn't have layer 3 or layer 2 network access.

Comment: Take a look at the answer to your other related question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187948/openbsds-pf-disable-network-access-for-a-given-user-except-for-ssh .  Although that is layer 3.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about workstations “behind” the OpenBSD box, you’ll want to add the workstations’ IP addresses to a pf table and create appropriate rules that reference this table.  `man pf.conf’ for details.  As for layer 2 access, you might want to elaborate a bit more here in terms of your requirements.